# Не устанавливается VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, setup

Пишет "Вы пытаетесь установить более раннюю версию продукта...". Раньше ставил VS 13 но удалил ее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл журнала:

```
[171C:1720][2016-03-09T09:07:59]i102: Detected related bundle: {318f27b6-e724-48c9-a373-07268286548f}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 12.0.31101.0, operation: Downgrade

[171C:1720][2016-03-09T09:07:59]i000: MUX:  Detected related bundle. Installing bundle Lcid:1049  related bundle tag: vs_ultimate,1049

[171C:1720][2016-03-09T09:07:59]i000: MUX:  A higher version bundle has already been installed.

[171C:1720][2016-03-09T09:07:59]e000: Error 0x80070642: BA aborted detect related bundle.

[171C:1720][2016-03-09T09:07:59]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to report detected related bundles.

[171C:1720][2016-03-09T09:07:59]i000: MUX:  Success Block: HigherVersionBlock : Вы пытаетесь установить более раннюю версию продукта, чем версия, установленная на данном компьютере.

[171C:1720][2016-03-09T09:07:59]i000: MUX:  Stop Block: OnlyOneInstanceBlock : В настоящий момент уже выполняется другой процесс установки. Дождитесь его завершения, а затем повторите попытку.

[171C:1720][2016-03-09T09:07:59]i000: MUX:  Detect Completed

[171C:1720][2016-03-09T09:07:59]i000: MUX:  Wait for View to be loaded

[171C:1760][2016-03-09T09:07:59]i000: MUX:  Detect Completed, now create view

[171C:1720][2016-03-09T09:07:59]i000: MUX:  View loaded

[171C:1720][2016-03-09T09:07:59]i000: MUX:  Go to Blocker page.

[171C:1720][2016-03-09T09:07:59]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x80070642
```

Comment: перезагрузить комп пробовали?

Comment: @KoVadim не помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо удалять через утилиты типа geek uninstaller или [VisualStudioUninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller)

Попробуйте через regedit удалить ветку нужной версии:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\

Еще посмотрите обновления VS их тоже нужно удалять